# How to update model from database in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, model, mysql-connector

I have an existing model for a MySQL database. I've added a new table in my database and now I want to update the model.

But when I right-click in the Model browser and select Update Model from Database... I get following message:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.VSDesigner.Data.Local.ConnectionStringConverterServiceException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: ''.
```

Application works just fine with existing model. I mean, data is successfully fetched when needed and all.

What might cause the problem with updating the model? Is it because of Express edition? How can I resolve the problem?

**UPDATE:**

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="OtherDbDataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.EF.OtherDb.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.EF.OtherDb.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.EF.OtherDb.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=id;Password=password;Host=localhost;Database=otherdb;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DbDataContext" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=id;password=password;Persist Security Info=True;database=db" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="DbDataConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=id;password=password;Persist Security Info=True;database=db" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the connector/net for mysql doesn't fully support express versions. Take a look at this post: [Mysql - Visual Web Developer - Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492452/mysql-visual-web-developer-entity-framework)

Comment: Thank you. Just checked with the full version of Studio and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Solved this problem by deleting all connectionstrings from config file. After that when you update model it prompts you to add connectionstrings and everything is working normally.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

My problem with this was related to the `Event Log` full. Deleted event log entries and that solved the problem. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your provider in machine.config file. This happens when the provider is not properly registered in the machine.config file.

Comment: I've added connection strings to `machine.config` but the same error keep showing.

Comment: which connectionstring are you using right now in your web.config ??

Comment: also try to uninstall and installing the MySQL provider component. This might solve the problem

Comment: reinstalling also didn't help

Comment: those were in the known issues to me with such kind of problems...sorry i couldn't help much then....Anyways, I have posted this question in asp.net mvc forum....will update you if i get an answer....

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the lowest config level closest to the .edmx file which is the app.config.
All in all the problem is connection related and not a problem in the designer IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Visual Studio 2012 Professional. After removing connection string from App.config, I cannot add new connection in "Update from database" window. MySQL Data source was missing.

Solved by installing MySQL for Visual Studio (for me it was 1.1.3 version). I had the opportunity to create connections to MySQL database. I revert connection string and even with old connection string all was fine.

Hope it helps.